# Can I use Google AdWords to advertise on my competitors sites after that visitor left my site?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, remarketing

For Google Adwords re-marketing, display ads are shown to visitors have been to your site previously. So when the go to a web site displaying AdSense, it is likely that re-marketing ad will be displayed to them.

Is there a way to do the same for if a visitor has visited a competitors site. i.e. if a visitor goes to one of my competitor sites, I want the display ads they see, to be mine.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have no control over what ads will be displayed.  There is some control over the genre of the content, but that's it.

Comment: Additionally, there is no way to tell if a user has visited a competitor's site without a third-party cookie tracking their activity, which means the competitor would need to be using the same tracking service and allow access to the data from that service.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy remarketing ads from within AdWords.  [Here is an article](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/re-marketing-guide/) that explains how to do so:

1. Log into AdWords
2. Visit the "Campaigns" tab
3. From the campaign folders list, select "Control panel and library"
4. Select "Audiences"
5. Create a new audience
6. Name the list and add a description
7. Set the time period from which the users have visited your site (default 30 days)
8. Put the code that Google gives you into your pages